# How to make this text even with my image? Layout issue

Tags: html, css

On this page, I need to make my text even with my image.

http://neilson.webege.com/principals.html

No matter what I've tried with different div classes and other ideas, I have not found a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Put them in the same div and float your text to the right.

Comment: Or float them both left and remove the margin from the text div.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this.

The first one: put the both in `div`s and make those `div`s vertically align by using  `vertical-align: top;` and `display: inline-box;`

Another solution is to put them in the same `div` and have the text `float: right`.

A third, more old school solution (don't use this one unless all else fails, it's not meant for this purpose and considered bad practice) is to make a table with one `tr` and two `td`s in one you can put the photo, in the other the text.

IMO the second one would be your best option, since it's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have the image and text in the same div. Float your text to the right.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://matthewjamessullivan.com/assets/logoJumbotron.png" alt""/>
    <p class="floatRightClass">Some text here</p>
</div>
```

This approach should solve your issue.

Here is a fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewJamesMP/HgvCL/19/

***The fiddle also includes another approach as well.***

Hope this helps!